# Digital Certificate Parsing Library in C++?

Tags: c++, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I used Crypto++ for my application. However it lacks a digital certificate parser. I know that openSSL has one, but I have to learn the whole library again.

Is there some parsing library existing for C++? All I want is to read the certificate and extract some fields, including the public key.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any really common [ASN.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) libraries, but the format as used by certificate files is actually dead easy to parse.